# Register Generic Interface in Startup in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have below interface and it's implementations.

Interface:

```
public interface ITrigger<T>  where T : class
{
    void Send(T bodyContent);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AdminTrigger : ITrigger<Admin>
{
    public void Send(Admin bodyContent)
    {
        //
    }
}
    
public class TeacherTrigger : ITrigger<Teacher> 
{
    public void Send(Teacher bodyContent)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Without generic implementation, I was able to register them like

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AdminTrigger>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TeacherTrigger>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<Func<UserType, ITrigger)>>(provider => key => {
    switch (key)
    {
        case UserType.Admin:
            return provider.GetService<AdminTrigger>();
        case UserType.Teacher:
            return provider.GetService<TeacherTrigger>();
        default: return null;
    }
});
```

But now I am getting an error at

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Func<UserType, ITrigger)>>(provider => key => {
```

> Using generic type `ITrigger<T>` requires 1 type argument

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want to register a delegate type and not register `ITrigger<>` using a delegate to create it?

Comment: @madreflection I had to use delegate since there are 2 implementation of ITrigger.

Comment: Without a common base interface, this design isn't going to work. If you made an `ITriggerFactory` interface and registered an implementation of that, you'd be in the same situation because the factory can't return a common type.  Maybe if you introduced a non-generic `ITrigger` interface and had `ITrigger<T>` inherit from that, but you'd still have to cast to `ITrigger<Admin>` or `ITrigger<Teacher>` once you got something. How did you expect to use the injected `Func<UserType, ITrigger>`, anyway?

Comment: @madreflection: I think you are right, Now I don't need delegate. I simply register like `services.AddTransient<ITrigger<Admin>, AdminTrigger>();
services.AddTransient<ITrigger<Teacher>, TeacherTrigger>();`